# AngularJS $scope.push items from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to create a shopping cart application. For this application, the intention is to add the product to the cart by an `onclick()` event. The `ng-click` function. The problem I'm having is that the `onclick()` event does literally nothing. As to say the event is called but nothing's changing and there isn't an error in the console.

So, first of all, i'm using the prestashop webservice for this application. The webservice is a rest API that connects to an existing prestashop installation.

First, I'll show the HTML containing the products. In this case the `ng-repeat` and `bind / value` options are data from the DB (`$http.get`). With the `ng-model` I'm able to obtain the data. (created a test with an alert.

**This is my HTML**

```js
// Cart system
myApp.controller('CartController', function($http, $scope) {
    // Get the products and cart products
    $http.get('config/get/getProducts.php').then(function(response){
        $scope.products = response.data.products.product
    });
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="CartController">
        
<div class="input-group col-xl-6 col-lg-8 col-sm-10 padding-t-20 padding-l-100">
   <span class="bc-f3f3f3 no-border input-group-addon">
    <svg width="20px" height="20px" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/><line x1="18" x2="30" y1="18" y2="30"/>
    </svg>
   </span>
  <input type="text" class="bc-f3f3f3 form-control no-border" ng-model="productname"  placeholder="{{ 'Zoek of scan producten' | translate }}" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
<div class="align-center tcolor-2a95cf text-center padding-t-25 padding-s-45 no-margin row">
 <div ng-if="product.active == 1" class="productimg col-4" ng-repeat="product in products  | filter:productname | orderBy: 'name'">
  <img ng-value="{{reference}}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm{{product.id}}"  ng-value="{{ean13}}" alt="{{product.name.language}}" src="https://sdwebdesign.nl/prestademo/{{product.id}}-home_default/{{product.name.language}}.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
  <p ng-bind="product.name.language"></p>
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm{{product.id}}"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content product-modal">
     <div class="modal-header product-modal-header no-border">
      <div class="container">
                            <ng-form name="products" ng-controller="CartController">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="hidden col-12 product">
                                        <h3 title="product_id" type="number" id="product_id" aria-describedby="" ng-model="product.id" ng-bind="product.id" ng-value="product.id"></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12 product text-center">
                                        <h3 title="product_name" id="product_name" aria-describedby="" ng-model="product.name.language" ng-bind="product.name.language" ng-value="product.name.language"></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-12">
                                        <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Prijs: ' | translate }}</label>
                                        <h3 title="product_price" type="text" id="product_price" aria-describedby="" class="form-control" ng-model="product.price" ng-bind="product.price"></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-12">
                                        <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Kies uw maat' | translate }}</label>
                                        <select title="product_size" type="text" name="product_size" id="product_size" class="form-control" ng-model="product.size" aria-describedby="">
                                            <option>S</option>
                                            <option>M</option>
                                            <option>L</option>
                                            <option>XL</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="no-padding product col-12">
                                        <label class="d-flex">{{ 'Aantal:' | translate }}</label>
                                        <input title="product_quantity" type="text" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity" class="form-control" aria-describedby="" ng-model="product.quantity" value="1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row margin-t-15">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <button class="btn-primary" ng-click="addToCart(product)" type="submit" value=" add ">
                                            Toevoegen aan winkelwagen
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-form>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer no-border product-modal-footer">
      <a data-dismiss="modal">{{ 'Sluit' | translate }}</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**This is the JS that obtain's the data and tries to push the product. The HTML is the cart itself.**

```js
$scope.addToCart = function(product) {
        var product_id = product.id;
        var product_name = product.name.language;
        var product_price = product.price;
        var product_size = product.size;
        var product_quantity = product.quantity;

        $scope.cartProduct = {
            id: product_id,
            name: product_name,
            price: product_price,
            size: product_size,
            quantity: product_quantity
        };

        $scope.cartProducts = [];
        $scope.cartProducts.push(
         $scope.cartProduct
        );

        $scope.cartProduct = {};

  console.log(product_id + product_name + product_price + product_size + product_quantity);
        angular.copy(product_name);
        console.log(angular.copy(product_name));
    };
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="cartProduct in cartProducts" class="row checkout margin-t-15">
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <p>
   id: {{cartProduct.id}}
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <p>
   name: {{cartProduct.name}}
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <p>
   quantity: {{cartProduct.quantity}}
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <p>
   Remove
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

To make it easier, the full controller is:

```js
myApp.controller('CartController', function($http, $scope) {
    // Get the products and cart products
    $http.get('config/get/getProducts.php').then(function(response){
        $scope.products = response.data.products.product
    });

    // Get the cart
    $http.get('config/cart/getCart.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.carts = response.data.carts.cart
    });

    // Stock check
    $http.get('config/get/getStock.php').then(function (response) {
        $scope.stock_availables = response.data.stock_availables.stock_available
    });

    $scope.addToCart = function(product) {
        var product_id = product.id;
        var product_name = product.name.language;
        var product_price = product.price;
        var product_size = product.size;
        var product_quantity = product.quantity;

        $scope.cartProduct = {
            id: product_id,
            name: product_name,
            price: product_price,
            size: product_size,
            quantity: product_quantity
        };

        $scope.cartProducts = [];
        $scope.cartProducts.push(
         $scope.cartProduct
        );

        $scope.cartProduct = {};

  console.log(product_id + product_name + product_price + product_size + product_quantity);
        angular.copy(product_name);
        console.log(angular.copy(product_name));
    };
});
```

So what I'm trying is to push the product to the cart. As you can see I've tried some other push examples I've found but sadly those aren't working.

See this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqazkqu5/1/) for an example

If you have any other questions please ask.

As always, Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need to see some data to help you. In your addToCart function, are you able to see "product" when you console log? What about $scope.cartProduct before the push and $scope.cartProducts after push?

Comment: @VijayMenon hi, yes i am, the product is a JSON data string obtained from the database. First i had some troubles with selecting the data but now, using the console.log() i do get the data equal to the data that is shown. Before the push the data is obtained within the variables. The problem is when pushing that nothing is shown on the other end in the cart. Since i'm currently traveling and responding through my mobile phone i can't really give you a better (visual) example. But if you need one please let me know and i'll create one.

Comment: Are both these HTML's referring the same controller? I see a productsController and cartController in your code. Please create a plunker/fiddle when you get time.

Comment: @VijayMenon I'm using only the cartController. I'm trying to edit my question but i'm recieving an error, for now i'll set the JSfiddle here. I'll add it to my question a.s.a.p. http://jsfiddle.net/kqazkqu5/1/

Comment: Please setup a working fiddle rather than a copy of your code here. Include all the external libraries and get the data from a local json file and demonstrate what you are trying to do.